# influxdb: calculating duration of boolean events?

Tags: influxdb

I have data in an influxdb database from a door sensor.  This is a boolean sensor (either the door is open (value is `false`) or it is closed (value is `true`)), and the table looks like:

```
name: door
--------------
time            value
1506026143659488953 true
1506026183699139512 false
1506026751433484237 true
1506026761473122666 false
1506043848850764808 true
1506043887602743375 false
```

I would like to calculate how long the door was open in a given period of time.  The [ELAPSED](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.3/query_language/functions/#elapsed) function gets me close, but I'm not sure how to either (a) restrict it to only those intervals for which the intitial value is `false`, or (b) identify "open" intervals from the output of something like `select elapsed(value, 1s) from door`.

I was hoping I could do something like:

```
select elapsed(value, 1s), first(value) from door
```

But that doesn't get me anything useful:

```
name: door
--------------
time            elapsed first
0               true
1506026183699139512 40  
1506026751433484237 567 
1506026761473122666 10  
1506043848850764808 17087   
1506043887602743375 38
```

I was hoping for something more along the lines of:

```
name: door
--------------
time            elapsed first
1506026183699139512 40  true
1506026751433484237 567 false
1506026761473122666 10  true
1506043848850764808 17087   false
1506043887602743375 38  true
```

Short of extracting the data myself and processing it in e.g. python, is there any way to do this via an influxdb query?

Comment: doesn't look like it is supported today - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959196/calculating-duration-between-a-start-and-end-event-in-influxdb?rq=1. Lack of native query support also means that there is no way to display this info in viz tools like Grafana. I have only got this to work with client side processing and adding an extra info into a measurement that can be used for rendering in Grafana.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem as well, I wanted to sum the durations of times for which a flag is on, which is pretty common in signal processing in time series libraries, but influxdb just doesn't seem to support that very well. I tried INTEGRATE with a flag of value 1 but it just didn't seem to give me correct values. In the end, I resorted to just calculating intervals in my data source, publishing those as a separate field in influxdb and summing them up. It works much better that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I have found so far:

https://community.influxdata.com/t/storing-duration-in-influxdb/4669

The idea is to store the boolean event as `0`or `1` and to store each state changes with two entries with one unit of time difference. It would look something like this:

```
name: door
--------------
time            value
1506026143659488953 1
1506026183699139511 1
1506026183699139512 0
1506026751433484236 0
1506026751433484237 1
1506026761473122665 1
1506026761473122666 0
1506043848850764807 0
1506043848850764808 1
1506043887602743374 1
1506043887602743375 0
```

It should then be possible to use a query like this:

```
SELECT integral(value) FROM "door" WHERE time > x and time < y
```

I'm new to influx so let me know if this is a bad way of doing things today. I also haven't tested the example I've written here.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. After running into this wall with InfluxDB and finding no clean solutions here or elsewhere, I ended up switching to TimescaleDB (PostgreSQL-based) and solving it with a SQL [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html), using `lag()` to calculate the delta to the previous time value.

For the OP's dataset, a possible solution looks like this:

```
SELECT
  "time",
  ("time" - lag("time") OVER (ORDER BY "time"))/1000000000 AS elapsed,
  value AS first
FROM door
ORDER BY 1
OFFSET 1;  -- omit the initial zero value
```

Input:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE "door" (time bigint, value boolean);
INSERT INTO "door" VALUES
  (1506026143659488953, true),
  (1506026183699139512, false),
  (1506026751433484237, true),
  (1506026761473122666, false),
  (1506043848850764808, true),
  (1506043887602743375, false);
```

Output:

```
        time         | elapsed | first 
---------------------+---------+-------
 1506026183699139512 |      40 | f
 1506026751433484237 |     567 | t
 1506026761473122666 |      10 | f
 1506043848850764808 |   17087 | t
 1506043887602743375 |      38 | f
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Very nice! I've worked a bit with timescaledb in the past, but at the time I was frustrated by the lack of data retention policies. It looks like things may have changed since I last looked.

Comment: Looks like InfluxDB 2 has a native solution: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/query-data/flux/monitor-states/