# Calculate state duration with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, influxdb

I have the following `pandas` dataframe representing some time series data when a certain signal was switched on (`True` state):

| datetime | state |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 01:00:00 | True |
| 2021-01-01 04:00:00 | True |
| 2021-01-01 05:30:00 | False |
| 2021-02-01 23:00:00 | True |
| 2021-03-01 01:30:00 | False |
| 2021-05-10 06:00:00 | True |

I need to calculate for how long was the signal in `True` state for each day as shown in the table below.

| datetime | duration(1h) |
| --- | --- |
| 01.01.2021 | 4.5 |
| 02.01.2021 | 1 |
| 03.01.2021 | 1.5 |
| 04.01.2021 | 0 |
| 05.01.2021 | 18 |

I tried to do it on the [database level using InfluxQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67703509/influxdb-calculate-for-how-long-was-a-signal-switched-on), but with no result so I decided to do it in Python instead.

Here's the example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'state': [True, True, False, True, False, True], 'datetime': ['2021-01-01T01:00:00Z', '2021-01-01T04:00:00Z', '2021-01-01T05:30:00Z', '2021-01-02T23:00:00Z', '2021-01-03T01:30:00Z', '2021-01-05T06:00:00Z']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])) # set datetime as DatetimeIndex
```

I've tried options with converting the boolean values to integers and then using `scipy.integrate` to get the area beneath the plot corresponding with the duration. Also tried some approaches with getting the timedelta between the consecutive point and doing some cumulative sum there, but no luck again.

I think the main problem is the grouping by days (notice the `True` duration between `2021-02-01 23:00:00` and `2021-03-01 01:30:00` - it aggregates to 1h on 2021-02-01 and 1.5h on 2021-03-01).

If anyone has any advice on has to achieve this with `pandas`, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try:

1. Convert to `datetime`.
2. use `pivot_table` to restructure the `dataframe`.
3. `fill` the missing values for a `particular day` with suitable `values`.
4. calculate the `difference`.
5. use `asfreq('1D'`) to fill the `missing days`.
6. fill `NAN` with `0`.

```
df.datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime, format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=[df.datetime.dt.date],
                     columns='state', values='datetime', aggfunc='first')
df1[True] = df1[True].fillna(pd.to_datetime(df1.index.to_series()))
df1[False] = df1[False].fillna(pd.to_datetime(
    df1.index.to_series()) + pd.DateOffset(+1))
result = (df1[False] - df1[True]).asfreq('1D').fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0))
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
datetime
2021-01-01   0 days 04:30:00
2021-01-02   0 days 01:00:00
2021-01-03   0 days 01:30:00
2021-01-04   0 days 00:00:00
2021-01-05   0 days 18:00:00
Freq: D, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this works for the given example, however I had to update pandas for this to work, I had 0.19.x and it didn't work, upgrading it to 0.20.3 seems to be working but I'd rather avoid it since a lot of code is working with the current version and not a lot of it is tested.

Also, I'm trying to figure out what parts to change if I have more "dense" data points. For example, I have several points each minute and I want the results to show the duration in seconds for each 1 minute interval.